# What is included in set #7155?

Tags: sets

I found an open box LEGO #7155 at a local Goodwill.

The funny thing is that there are 3 unopened bags in the box, 3 booklets (instructions, and 2 other small booklets along with 4 large pieces that are not in bags.

The set looks to be complete, but my question is this.  Is this how this set came in the box?  Are the 4 pieces (2 large beige oval for front of ship and 2 - 2x16 brown pieces) supposed to be loose in the box.

Everything looks pretty much untouched and brand new other than the fact that the box is open and Goodwill can't help themselves with writing on boxes.

Answer (score 4):

It is very common for Lego to pack larger parts like [Plate 2 x 16](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4282) not in a seperate bag, for sets this size.

If I look at the inventory of set [7155](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7155-1), and compare this with sets I built over the years, I think 3 bags for the parts could be correct:

- bag with minifig parts and small parts like 1x1's and 1x2's;
- bag with large size parts like the 4x8 plates;
- bag with remaining parts.